# Show only rows that contains specific value in specific row

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, datatable

I need to sort all the rows only to show the rows that contain same `Session["ID"]` in the `userId` column.

This is my code

```
public void GetAllUsers()
{
    Response.Write("<table border='1' class='tables'> <tr>");
    Response.Write("<td align='center'>שם המשימה</td>");
    Response.Write("<td align='center'>פירוט המשימה</td>");
    Response.Write("<td align='center'>מועד אחרון</td>");

    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        Response.Write("<tr>");
        Response.Write("<td align='center'>" + row["title"].ToString() + "</td> ");
        Response.Write("<td align='center'>" + row["description"].ToString() + "</td> ");
        Response.Write("<td align='center'>" + row["isDone"].ToString() + "</td> ");
        Response.Write("</tr>");
    }

    Response.Write("</table>");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
     if (row["userid"].ToString() == Session["ID"].ToString())
     { 
         Response.Write("<tr>");
         Response.Write("<td align='center'>" + row["title"].ToString() + "</td> ");
         Response.Write("<td align='center'>" + row["description"].ToString() + "</td> ");
         Response.Write("<td align='center'>" + row["isDone"].ToString() + "</td> ");
         Response.Write("</tr>");
     }   
}
```